# How to trigger an action after x seconds in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, timer

I have been trying to accomplish two main goals that I'm having a headache with. Sorry if it's a simple fix, I am a still bit new to Swift/SwiftUI.

1. Trigger an action after a certain time has elapsed.
2. Trigger an `@State` to change value based on how much time has passed.

I've searched through Stack Overflow and found answers suggesting to use a timer:

```swift
struct CurrentDateView : View {
    @State var now = Date()

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .current, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(now)")
            .onReceive(timer) {
                self.now = Date()
            }
    }
}
```

But how would I incorporate this so that something like `@State` can be used change my value to `false` after 7.5 seconds has passed:

```swift
@State randomTF : Bool = true
```

Or a `Text("Please Enter Above")` to change to `Text("Sorry Too Late")` after 7.5 seconds has passed?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Create a delay, which then sets the `@State` property `hasTimeElapsed` to `true` when the time has elapsed, updating the view body.

With Swift 5.5 and the new concurrency updates (`async` & `await`), you can now use [`task(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(_:)) like the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var hasTimeElapsed = false

    var body: some View {
        Text(hasTimeElapsed ? "Sorry, too late." : "Please enter above.")
            .task(delayText)
    }

    private func delayText() async {
        // Delay of 7.5 seconds (1 second = 1_000_000_000 nanoseconds)
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 7_500_000_000)
        hasTimeElapsed = true
    }
}
```

See more info about `Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68715267/9607863).

---

#### Older versions

Xcode 13.0+ now supports concurrency, backwards compatible! However, here is still the 'old' way to do it:

You can use [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) to delay something. Trigger it with [`onAppear(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:)) (which happens when the view first appears). You could also hook the delay up to a Button instead if wanted.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var hasTimeElapsed = false

    var body: some View {
        Text(hasTimeElapsed ? "Sorry, too late." : "Please enter above.")
            .onAppear(perform: delayText)
    }

    private func delayText() {
        // Delay of 7.5 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 7.5) {
            hasTimeElapsed = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't feel like the intended way to do this... especially since SwiftUI views are ephemeral and can be destroyed and re-initialized at any time. I'd expect they would intend some Combine publisher here instead

Answer (score 26):

`.delay` is built-in to Swift animations. I achieved my goal of launching an animation 0.5 seconds after a view appeared with the following code:

```
 .onAppear(perform: {
    withAnimation(Animation.spring().delay(0.5)) {
         self.scale = 1.0
    }
 })
```

Comment: This is perfect. I display an occasional error message (like 'account unknown' or 'incorrect password') but I want it to disappear after several seconds. Two thumbs up!

Answer (score 15):

// Add a delay of 1 sec

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
   // your function
}
```

Comment: Clear and simple, thank you

Comment: you may use background threads if the function does not affect the view.

Comment: @ShereifSRF Agreed. So in the case of background, we can use it like this,

DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), qos: .background) {

       // your function

}

Answer (score 7):

From on John's answer, that `task` is performed **before** the view appears. From apple's doc:

> Adds an asynchronous task to perform before this view appears.

So this is not really "onAppear" and, I think, there's a chance it can be performed before view appears if delay is very short. Which may not be expected.

I suggest keep using `.onAppear` and just have a `Task` inside. No need to declare any extension functions.
Like this:

```
    .onAppear {
      Task { @MainActor in
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.1))
        // your code here
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as:

```swift
Text("\(now)")
.onAppear(delay: 1) {
    self.now = Date()
}
```

Using these extensions, which are reusable across projects and address some related issues as well:

```swift
public extension TimeInterval {
    var nanoseconds: UInt64 {
        return UInt64((self * 1_000_000_000).rounded())
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
public extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {
    static func sleep(_ duration: TimeInterval) async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration.nanoseconds)
    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, macOS 12.0, *)
public extension View {
    func onAppear(delay: TimeInterval, action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        task {
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(delay)
            } catch { // Task canceled
                return
            }
            
            await MainActor.run {
                action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```