# How to await x seconds with async await Swift 5.5

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift5, swift-concurrency

How do I use the new Swift 5.5 `await` keyword to wait for a duration of time?

Normally, with completion handlers, you would have something like this by using [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)'s [`asyncAfter(deadline:execute:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300020-asyncafter):

```
func someLongTask(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        completion(Int.random(in: 1 ... 6))
    }
}

someLongTask { diceRoll in
    print(diceRoll)
}
```

How can this be converted to using `async` & `await` in Swift 5.5?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### iOS 16+ / macOS 13+

There's a newer API, [`sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)), used like so:

```
// 3 seconds
try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(3))
```

---

#### iOS <16 / macOS <13

You can use [`Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3862701-sleep) to wait for a specific duration. This is measured in **nanoseconds**, not seconds.

Here's an example:

```
func someLongTask() async -> Int {
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000) // 1 second
    return Int.random(in: 1 ... 6)
}

Task {
    let diceRoll = await someLongTask()
    print(diceRoll)
}
```

It may be easier to use an extension for sleep so you can just pass in seconds:

```
extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {
    static func sleep(seconds: Double) async throws {
        let duration = UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000)
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
    }
}
```

Which would now be called like so:

```
try await Task.sleep(seconds: 1)
```

Note that sleep is called with `try`. An error is thrown if the sleep is cancelled. If you don’t care if it’s cancelled, just `try?` is fine.

Comment: Is the bug fixed where this wasn't actually working in the early betas?

Comment: @matt It's running fine for me now, what was the issue during early betas?

Comment: Anything longer than a few nanoseconds we wouldn't actually sleep. :) See the comments after my https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929769/341994 Anyway, glad to hear it's working now!

Comment: @matt Ah it is working now. I also just timed the example with a regular `DispatchQueue` and they both take the correct amount of time (roughly).

Comment: What's the reason for the `where Success == Never, Failure == Never`? Isn't that rather limiting?

Comment: @matt The linked documentation (in the answer) to the sleep method says: "`Available when Success is Never and Failure is Never.`". I found this after I couldn't get it to compile without this `where` clause. If there is a less limiting version, that would be better.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically the case for _all_ the Thread static funcs so perhaps we just shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 15):

From iOS 16 you can use `.seconds` directly like this:

```
try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(10))
```